# What is the sanskrit name for the "Star of David"?

Tags: name, symbolism, symbols

Is there a Sanskrit name or term for the "Star of David" itself, since archeological evidence shows it being part of Vedic culture in India?

Comment: can you please give some good references regarding such archeological evidences?

Answer (score 2):

There is no word in Sanskrit for star of David. Intertwining triangles are part of *yantras*. Wikipedia has a general descriptive page on *yantras*. Downward pointing triangles are symbols of the female, *yoni* or *shakti* element; and upward pointing triangles are symbolic of the male, *lingum or vahni (fire)* or *shiva* element. Thus the intertwining of the two is the intertwining of the male and female principles, Nirguna and Saguna Brahman, Shiva and Shakti, the Yin and the Yang, the positive and the negative. The two opposites always interacting with one another. The one appearing as two.

In the Greek lexicon, the Greek letter 'Delta' which is and upward pointing triangle, symbolized the female.

See *Myths and Symbols in Indian Art and Civilization* by Heinrich Zimmer pp 147-8.